# Excel Substitute Function

Tags: excel-formula

I want to take what is in column A and replace the number after the "=" with new number.  I need a formula that identifies the 6 numbers or letters after the = and replaces with column A

```
111111     showstocknumnber//details.php?vid=111111
222222     showstocknumnber//details.php?vid=111111
345673     showstocknumnber//details.php?vid=111111
```

The 111111 after the = could be any string of 6 letters and numbers.  The contents of column b are a URL.

Comment: in column C autofill down =SUBSTITUTE(B1,"111111",A1,1)

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same then I would just build a new string:

Assuming you are in row 1:

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND("=",B1))&A1
```

What is does is: It takes everything until the equal sign (cutting what comes after) from the URL and then just appends what's in column A.

Answer (score 0):

If the string `showstocknumnber//details.php?vid=` always the same then try this:

```
="showstocknumnber//details.php?vid="&A1
```

Answer (score 0):

And just in case the URL isn't always the same:

```
=REPLACE(B1,FIND("=",B1)+1,6,A1)
```